# How to get data from MongoDB using c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to get data from my Mongo collection using filter. I get an error when I am trying to add the result of my filter into a `List<BsonDocument>`.

My code is :

```
  public List<BsonDocument> korisniciPrijava(ModelPrijavaKorisnika prKor)
    {
        try
        {
            var conString = "mongodb://172.16.1.24:27017";
            var Client = new MongoClient(conString);
            var DB = Client.GetDatabase("knjigoMata");
            var kolekcija = DB.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("kljenti");
            var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("lozinka", prKor.Lozinka);
            Task<List<BsonDocument>> task = kolekcija.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
            List<BsonDocument> PrijavljeniKorisnik = task.Result;
            foreach (var dc in PrijavljeniKorisnik)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dc );
            }
            return PrijavljeniKorisnik;
        }

        catch (MongoServerException ex)
        {


            MessageBox.Show("doslo je do greške s bazom");
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: I have an error in this line :  'List<BsonDocument> PrijavljeniKorisnik = task.Result;'

Comment: what error? Change your catch block to MessageBox.Show("doslo je do greške s bazom" + ex.ToString());, it will give more info.